# reusing views inside other views in Django

Tags: django

I have a few components on my website that appear on many pages. DRY in mind, I would like to factor them out in separate snippets that I can include in the views that need them.

If it were only static items, then an `{% include "snippet.html" %}` would be the perfect solution. How can achieve a similar thing for snippets that include forms (and hence logic in the view) or require calculations before being displayed? Also, I would like to be able to nest the snippets several levels deep.

I know I can put simple logic in the template, using `{% if ... %} ... {% endif %}` blocks, but this turns into horrible spagetthi very soon and I want to keep the business logic separated from the presentation logic.

I am imagining a pattern as follows (here with oversimplified business logic):

```
def view1(request):
    "Display some data"
    total = get_total_vote_count()
    return render(request, 'snippet1.html', {'total': total})

def view2(request, pk):
    "Display some data about the article with primary key pk."
    votes = get_votes_for_article(pk)
    render1 = view1(request)
    return render(request, 'snippet2.html', {'votes': votes, 'render1': render1})

def view3(request, pk):
    "Display article pk and some additional data from view1 and view2":
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    render2 = view2(request, pk)
    return render(request, 
                  'article.html', 
                  {'article': article, 'render2': render2},
                  )
```

with the templates something like:

```
# in snippet1.html:
<a href="overview.html">{{ total }}</a>

# in snippet2.html:
<p>Votes for this article: {{ votes }} out of {{ render1 }} total votes.</p>

# in page.html:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block "content" %}
  <h1>article.title</h1>
  <p>article.text</p>
  <small>{{ render2 }}</small>
{% end block "content" %}
```

Note that there will be more views that will use `view1` and `view2` (e.g. an overview of the votes for all articles); that is why I have factored them out in separate functions.

How can I make this work? 
Or is there a better trick in the Django toolbox to make this work without repeating view1 and view2 every time I want to use the same snippets in other views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what custom template tags - specifically, [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) - are for: rendering a template fragment with its own context.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I have found the following snippet which does the job: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1568/ Thanks!

Comment: That's fair enough I guess, but I don't see why those other utility functions need to be views at all. It seems like you're adding a lot of extra complexity where you don't need to: just put the code directly into the template tag definition.

Comment: Putting the code in the template tag would lead to code duplication because I would have to write a template tag for each view that I want to reuse, copying 90% of the code from the view. I want to be able to use view1 and view2 as views on their own, so the template tag should just call these views, which is what the linked djangosnippet does.

Answer (score 0):

what about django middleware, you can use middleware for this case. view1 and view2 repeating every time right ?. then attach the render1 and render2 to your request.

Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/